Rotted, leaking front struts
I dropped my Silverado off for brake work and the mechanic told me that my front struts are rotted and leaking very badly, and need to be replaced. How serious of a condition is this and what happens if I don't do anything to remedy the situation?

What is the yeat & engine of your Silverado?

Bad struts are a serious condition. When they don't work they will cause instability with controlling your vehicle, especially when cornering or driving through a curve. They also increase stopping distance. Also if replacing struts on one side it is highly recommended to do the other side as well. This is a safety issue.

Thanks @Jupiter, I guess I'm worried that the mechanic is just trying to squeeze money out of me. Is there any way I can verify for myself that they are "bad" (rotted/leaking) to justify the costs of repair?

One way is a visual inspection. Any oil found on them indicates a leak. Leaking struts need replaced. Also you can go to each corner of the vehicle. Put all your weight down on the car to compress the springs. Then quickly let it rise. It should rise and go back down to it's resting place. If the car continues to go up and down more than that, they are shot.
